# Unable to install any version of ubuntu in my laptop

Tags: installation, graphics, acpi

I have MSI -CR400 laptop.
Configuration of MSI-CR400

- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6600 @ 2.2O GHz
- RAM 4.00 GB
- VIDEO CARD: NVIDIA GEFORCE 8200M – 512MB [256MB VRAM + 256MB (SYSTEM SHARED)]
- HARD DRIVE: WESTERN DIGITAL 250GB

i dont know why i am unable to install any version of ubuntu. I tried with Usb Stick as well as Live cd. but process always hangs sometimes on 47% , sometimes on 76%.
I also try to install with Acpi-off. but installation always freezes. I read that problem is due to Nvidia graphics card. Kinldy suggest me. I also try ubuntu 12.04 LTS but its hangs on first page. it just show its native violet screen and freezes my all system and i have to manually off the system. Kinldy help me on this issue. I need ubuntu on priority.M an android developer and ubuntu is best of it.

Kindly suggest me , ubuntu is working fine on my desktop and other laptop.

Comment: Define "freezing"... Does it simply stay on the same percentage for a long time? That's normal on some systems (a bug, but normal). Just wait for an hour and if it's still like that you can assume it's stuck. Does it give you some kind of message saying the installation has failed? Can you still use your mouse and keyboard?

Comment: freezing means it does not respond after a long time. Long time is really long. I leave it for  2-3 hours , installation is not showing any progress. In other system its installing so fast.Also in freezing i cant move my mouse cursor etc. Its stuck every time.Ubuntu 10.04 Lts installation process start , but in 12.04 its stuck on first page and didnt see its install ubuntu option.Just a violet screen. nothing else.I dont get any failed message. My keyboard and mouse dont make any effect. Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my notebook I have onboard intel gfx plus an nvida card. In bios I can choose between discrete (Nvidia), internal(intel), or automatic (sytem will chose). In order to boot my ubuntu I need to either set the gfx option in bios to discrete or internal. Automatic will not work. You may check your bios wether you have a similar option.

Comment: I have an optimus notebook too, but I can't choose which GPU to use in BIOS, so I've been unable to install Linux. All attempts with all linux distros I have tried have frozen pretty early in the install process... :-(

Answer (score 1):

The reason appears to be that incompatible video-drivers start up at the same time as the installer.

**Solution:** Before starting the installer, go into the <kbd>F-</kbd>key  boot-options and enable `nomodeset` for the installation. Then after rebooting the machine, do the same thing and first install the proprietary Nvidia drivers and then reboot again.

After that point, you shouldn't need this boot option any more.

Answer (score 1):

First off , have you MD5 test the ISO before burning it to the USB!, have you tried using a different USB  brand? Try with Ubuntu 12.04 ISO ,  and which USB tool you used ! have you tried UNetbootin, or dd commands? Does your laptop happen to have a hybrid Graphic ( Intel/Nvidia ) > if so , there is a Switch in the BIOS , try to set off one of theme, then see how it goes!, if it sill freezes and hang on you ,then next up is to try one of the Kernel boot Parameters from GRUB .

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootParameters

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

it's simple ,when you see the Live-CD Window there is a key there that allows you to type commands to the kernel boot line ,  press tab to enter commands, delete "- -" from the inputline and try adding "nomodeset" and/or "noacpi" , then boot to the live-cd

if you have installed Ubuntu already but unable to reach the desktop, just after the BIOS screen press Shift or ESC that would make GRUB Menu to show up , then press "e" in grub to enter commands, and look for he line that starts with " linux  there .. add "nomodeset" or " noacpi " after "splash video" then boot to the desktop .

Answer (score 0):

Seems this particular laptop has some known problems for installing Ubuntu. Apparently the nv driver doesn't work good with the NVIDIA graphics and the proprietary driver from the Ubuntu 10.04 era doesn't work properly either. The link below outlines the problem, and how to work around it by manually installing the NVIDIA driver for Ubuntu 10.04.
http://www.linlap.com/wiki/msi+cr500

Comment: Hi, thax for reply.I tried to install ubuntu than go to its first page options page . Press F6 and go to other options and check in acpi-off options.But it does not work for me. If there is any other way than kinldy suggest me. Sorry to say i am really new in ubuntu. just suggest me . i will try my best. My live cd is booting successfully . I can install around 70-80 % Ubuntu 10.04. After than ubuntu stuck and keyboard mouse stop working. There is no acpi off option in my BIOS .IN ubuntu 12.04 i cant do anything , its stuck from first page.

Comment: Hi, I am already loss all my data during this process. so i am ready with  blank harddisk. I dont need windows.My laptop resolutin is 1280*720 .

Comment: ok, m trying this time as nomodeset boot option .M able to install ubuntu 9.04 successfully . but unable to upgrate it. its not working and its support is now not provided by ubuntu. Its expire verison of ubuntu. So , i want to install atleast ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Comment: Thought about trying 12.04? Unity takes some getting used to but it's pretty good after that.

Comment: Ok , i have live cd of 12.04. I have windows 7 installed in my laptop. I sud to remove completety or dual boot. Wat u will prefer. Windows is not in my priority . If ubuntu will work fine. M ok with it.

Comment: Hi, now i install ubuntu successfully . when i select ubuntu for GRUB loader. its again stuck. M still waiting for password screen. Here mouse is moving. So, i am waiting since 10 mins.My laptop is being overheated too. can graphics card can be reason behind this?

Comment: After installation my laptop still stuck .I try to update from update manager. I again get stuck , Mouse is still navigating. but click is not working.