# Ubuntu doesn't seem to load

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

Hello: I am trying to boot Ubuntu for the first time and something strange is happening. The Ubuntu menu doesn't load immediately, as the Installing Tutorial said it would, so I restart my computer and force it to boot from the DVD. A screen appears asking whether I want to install Ubuntu or try the live CD and, no matter what I choose, the same thing happens: it goes to a screen with the Ubuntu logo and five small lights that turn on and off as though it is loading... And nothing happens. Eventually, the lights stop turning on and off and the computer freezes.
Please note: it is a fairly new ASUS laptop, with Windows 10 pre-installed; I have tried both Ubuntu and Linux Mint and the same thing happens; I have checked and the DVD's (I have tried 3 times) were properly burned.
Any advice would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132257/unable-to-install-any-version-of-ubuntu-in-my-laptop/210781#210781) ? -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions?action=show&redirect=BootParameters

Comment: Have you try to check their MD5 sum first?

Comment: Thank both of you, it was two things combined: one was nomodeset and it was also a graphic card driver problem. FIxed now! :)